# Vue tabs multiple of same child component type wrong data

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have tabs which display forms. There are different types of forms, and each type of form can be open in its own tab 0 to X times. The issue is specifically when there are more than one of the same type of form open, plus at least one other type open:
[image]

In this scenario, when I change from Item Two back to Item One, the form shows the name prop from Item Two.

Here's how the tabs are setup:

```
<v-tabs
      dark
      background-color="blue-grey darken-4"
      show-arrows
      height="30"
      v-model="activeModel"
      class="fixed-tabs-bar"
      v-if="openTabs.length"
    >
      <v-tabs-slider color="accent"></v-tabs-slider>

  <v-tab v-for="item in openTabs" :key="item.id" class="pr-0 white--text" color="accent" active-class="" @click="setActiveTab(item)">
    <template class="white--text text-capitalize">
      <v-icon>
        {{ item.icon }}
      </v-icon>
      &nbsp;
      {{ item.name }}
      <div v-if="item.changes">*</div>
      <v-btn plain width="10" class="px-0" @click="closeTab(item.id)">
        <v-icon dark small width="10">mdi-close</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </template>
  </v-tab>
</v-tabs>
<v-tabs-items v-model="activeModel" style="background-color: #232323;">
  <v-tab-item v-for="item in openTabs" :key="item.id" style="height: 100%" :transition="false" eager>
    <BlockForm
      :key="item.id"
      v-if="activeTab.type === 'blocks' && item.type === 'blocks'"
      :name="openTabs[activeModel].name"
      :activeProject="activeProject"
    />
    <ItemForm :key="item.id" v-if="activeTab.type === 'items' && item.type === 'items'" :name="openTabs[activeModel].name" :projectName="activeProject" />
   ... More form types ...
   </v-tab-item>
</v-tabs-items>
```

And set looks like:

```
setActiveTab: function(item) {
  this.activeTab = item;
  this.activeType = item.type;
}
```

The name prop is specifically what is wrong in the data.

Comment: when you go back to the first tab from the second tab, can you see the first tab when you click on it more than once?

Comment: @bariskau no, it remains the second tab

Comment: You can try to use the $nextTick function in setActiveTab, I think it is not rendered.

Comment: What would I put inside the nextTick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<v-tab-item v-for="item in openTabs" :key="item.id" style="height: 100%" :transition="false" eager>
    <BlockForm
      :key="item.id"
      v-if="activeTab.type === 'blocks' && item.type === 'blocks'"
      :name="openTabs[activeModel].name"
      :activeProject="activeProject"
    />
    <ItemForm :key="item.id" v-if="activeTab.type === 'items' && item.type === 'items'" :name="openTabs[activeModel].name" :projectName="activeProject" />
   ... More form types ...
   </v-tab-item>
```

The main problem is that when you set the activeTab variable, the v-tab-item element is not re-rendered. Because you are using item-id as key. You can use nextTick or directly apply the solution below.

You can take a look at Vue [reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

```
:key="`${activeTab.id}-${item.id}`"
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Conceptually is it possible to maintain "copies" of each open tab component? The reason I ask is that each component uses the name prop to load data from the backend. With this implementation any changes that are made to the form and not saved are lost when tabs are switched.

Comment: @John, if you use v-if, the element is re-rendered when the condition is true. For this reason, you can provide control with v-show. It basically just hide the element with css. But don't forget to update the :key value to item.id and don't use :key attr in child components.